I can't find ways to fix tkinter on mac
I am using pygame to make an easy game and just want to import tkinter for pop-up window.
Here's my code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox 

def message_box(subject, content):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(subject, content)

And in the game loop:
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_n:
          message_box('Stone', 'Return')

When I run the game, it shows:

By the way, I am using pycharm.
If I delete the lines mentioned tk, it works properly.
I've tried to solved this problem with ActivateTcl:

Well, I downloaded but nothing happened. How can I fix this? Should I uninstall ActivateTcl?

There is no need at all to install ActiveTcl – it's entirely unrelated to the Tcl and Tkinter bundled with Python. How did you install Python to begin with?

You could try and brew install python-tk. For some versions of python on mac that's needed.

Following the steps I outlined here might help.

It looks like you are using both pygame and tkinter in the same project which is discouraged. Also please edit your question to include a [mre].
